# Creating synthetic data from existing data

Tags: machine-learning, synthetic-data

I have data with 8 features and 900 rows each. Those features are dependent on each other in some way. I want to conduct machine learning, but the data size is small. 
I was suggested to generate synthetic data from the existing data considering those correlations between the features. 
What solution can be applied to this problem?

Comment: That is a worthless pursuit. You don't gain information from randomly regenerating data from the original sample. You can't interpret the increased sample size as a if they were new data.